# passing integer as VARCHAR() datatype in an SQL query from python

Tags: python, sql, sqldatatypes

The database i am using (WRDS) mainly uses a web form for queries, so for that reason, primary keys in the database are stored as VARCHAR(6) despite being integers.

[image]

My query looks like this -
 `select gvkey from comp.sec_dprc where gvkey in (12142, 12141, 12138, 1300, 1722, 12635, 12850, 3144);`

Since this query is just a string passed to a function in python, i have no control over the datatype of the list of keys, so they are being read as numeric. This means my query does not find any matches.

I would like to be able to specify the varchar(6) datatype from the query, if possible . I tried;

```
cast((12142, 12141, 12138, 1300, 1722, 12635, 12850, 3144) as varchar(6)
```

and

```
(cast(12142 as varchar(6), cast(12141as varchar(6), cast(12138 as varchar(6), etc)
```

So far, i have not had any success. I have had even less success with WRDS customer support. If there is as solution i am missing, i would be absolutely ecstatic to find it.

Cheers

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  Also show what the data looks like *in the tables*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the values are numbers, then convert the *column* to a number:

```
where cast(gvkey as int) in (12142, 12141, 12138, 1300, 1722, 12635, 12850, 3144)
```

The syntax and best approach might differ by database, but the idea is the same.

Note:  You can get conversion errors if you are wrong about the contents being only digits.

Answer (score 0):

Why not go the opposite way and specify inside IN clause types to be VARCHAR?. Try like:

```
select gvkey from comp.sec_dprc where gvkey 
in ('12142', '12141', '12138', '1300', '1722', '12635', '12850', '3144')
```

Comment: An excellent thought, but this did not work for some reason... It was one of the first things i tried